# Python not importing all functions?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a script that imports another script, like this:

```
from mp_utils import *

login_response = login(...)
r = incomingConfig(...)
```

and mp_utils.py is like this:

```
import requests
import logging
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

def login( ... ):
    ...

def incomingConfig( ... ):
    ...
```

When running it, `login` works fine, but `incomingConfig` fails with:

```
Message: 'module' object has no attribute 'incomingConfig'
Exception: None
```

No idea why, any ideas?

funny thing is if import with python cli interactive, it works fine.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`from x import *` imports everything so that you don't have to name the module before you call a function. Try removing `mp_utils` from your function calls.

Answer (score 0):

It is importing all the functions correctly, when you import using `from` then you don't have to prefix `mp_utils` to call the functions, just you can call it by their name. To call `mp_utils` prefixed, use `import mp_utils` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference mp.utils before calling  incomingConfig.

By using a * import, it means you already added all the functions into the the current namespace. So you should be able to just make the call using `r = incomingConfig(...)`

If you want to make the call your way, you'd have to import it as
`import mp_utils`
Than later you can make the call.
`r = mp_utils.incomingConfig(...)`